# Can I localize my whole android app from a button click

Tags: java, android

I have to localize an android project for both English and Arabic users.
From the next link  I get codes for doing this task

[programmatically-change-language](http://snowpard-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html)

My activity_main.xml contains two buttons English button for changing my application ‘s texts  for English users,
 and Arabic button for changing my application’s texts for Arabic users.

On my activity_main.xml there are texts of buttons which are converted from the language to  another language  after pressing either English or Arabic button fine.

My question here

How  I can  convert  buttons’ texts on other activities ?
if  I try to  update  them through **updateTexts()** method , I will get   error :- 
unfortunately app has stopped (Because their activities didn’t start).

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    private Button English,Arabic;  
    private Locale myLocale;
    public void changeLang(String lang)
    {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    updateTexts();
    }

public void saveLocale(String lang)
{
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.commit();
}

public void loadLocale()
{
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
    changeLang(language);
}

private void updateTexts()
{

 English.setText(R.string.English);
 Arabic.setText(R.string.Arabic);

}
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.English= (Button)findViewById(R.id.English);
    this.Arabic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Arabic);

 Button  english = (Button) findViewById(R.id.English);
 english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  String lang = "en";
 switch (v.getId()) {
 case R.id.English:
 lang = "en";
 break;
 case R.id.Arabic:
 lang = "ar";
 break;
 default:
 break;  
 }
 changeLang(lang);
 }
 });
 Button  Arabic= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Arabic);
 english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
 String lang = "ar";
 switch (v.getId()) {
 case R.id.English:
lang = "en";
break;
case R.id.Arabic:
lang = "ar";
break;
default:
break;  
}
changeLang(lang);
}  
});
}}
```

Comment: Button's text can also be obtained from the string.xml configured for the locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem.
There is no need for updateTexts() method or `changed texts.
The texts are changed automatically just by clicking the appropriate button using my codes above.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Save locale in SharedPreferences:

```
/*
  SETTINGS_NAME - string variable or constant
  LANG_SETTINGS - lang settings identificator
  lang - language, en_US for example 
 */
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor = editor.putString(LANG_SETTINGS, lang);
editor.commit();
```

Load SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String lang = preferences.getString(LANG_SETTING, "")
```

Comment: getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);   this code doesn't work , may be if I use context it would work but how I use context.

Comment: Your Actvity is Context

Comment: if I try new MainActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null) ; the application stopped

Comment: Does You using this method in activity?

Comment: Have you using correct language code? https://developers.google.com/igoogle/docs/i18n?csw=1

Comment: This needs to be called by all actvities in onCreate method.

Comment: I suppose your code will work , how it could be read from values-en\Strings.xml or values-ar\Strings.xml files?

Comment: It will read depending on localization when you read it after localization changes again.

Comment: You need to reset content view or change texts of views Yourself.

Comment: As you see I changed texts of views via updateTexts() method the problem I can't do that for all application 's texts and that is the problem!

Comment: You need to check setting in every onCreate() method and set content view after that only

Comment: I understand from you I should check language in every onCreate() method if language chosen in Arabic I should  update texts to arabic language but how that could be achieved programmatically please . How can I check language chosen by the user in MainActivity please?